# How to link my app with WhatsApp when WhatsApp Business is also on the device?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

WhatsApp Business opens in place of WhatsApp. How can I link only to WhatsApp?
Here is the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send phone="+phonestr+"&text="+messagestr));

startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the target package (application ID) that you want to handle the intent using `Intent.setPackage`.
But if the package is not installed it will throw an exception so keep in mind to handle that as well.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send phone="+phonestr+"&text="+messagestr));

i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

startActivity(i);
```

In addition you can try different packages after getting `ActivityNotFound` exception. For example try WhatsApp and if it threw an Exception, then try WhatsApp Business or whatever

Comment: And I guess WhatsApp Business had been set as default for this link by user in the last time they've chose WABusiness, probably by clicking Always button on chooser